# 'Thread' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: multithreading, python-multithreading

I am creating a CustomThread class, and I am trying to use the attribute "value". But apparently it seems like "value" attribute no longer exists.
Any pointers here to solve?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Val and value are different.

Value=thread.value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).